# "Для него/нее" или "Для этого", когда мы говорим о процессах

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, местоимения, местоимение

> - Наружный тюнинг автомобиля и используемые для **него** товары.
> - Для создания таких файлов и чтобы назначить нужные для **него** сочетания клавиш <...>

Пытаюсь понять, должны ли мы использовать в таких случаях слова **него** и **неё*, либо же следует использовать слово **этого**:

> - Наружный тюнинг автомобиля и используемые для **этого** товары.
>   v* Для создания таких файлов и чтобы назначить нужные для **этого** сочетания клавиш <...>

Полный пример второго предложения, по запросу Eagle:

> Файлы, имена которых включают такие суффиксы, должны создаваться в виде копий — путём нажатия заранее назначенных сочетаний клавиш — и такие копии следует использовать только в качестве временных; например, в качестве простой системы контроля версий. Для их создания и чтобы назначить нужные для него сочетания клавиш, тебе потребуется продвинутый файловый менеджер или какой-то скрипт.

Comment: *«Для создания таких файлов и чтобы назначить нужные для него сочетания клавиш»* — предложение не полное, нельзя понять о чём идёт речь. Дайте, пожалуйста, более полный текст предложения. Что «Для создания таких файлов…»?

Comment: @Eagle Добавил :-) Именно из-за него всё и затевалось. Пишу документ об именах файлов, и хочется чтоб всё было сформулировано предельно четко и аккуратно, в том числе с точки зрения языковых норм.

Comment: Написано сложно предложение, надо подумать. Тут, по-моему, ошибка в другом: "создание" и "назначить" — это не однородные члены, соединённые союзом «и».

Comment: Два местоимения «для них» и «для него» трудно воспринимаются. Нужно перефразировать мысль, например: *«Для создания временных копий этих файлов, путём нажатия комбинаций горячих клавиш, тебе потребуется продвинутый файловый менеджер или какой-то скрипт, позволяющие назначать сочетания клавиш для таких операций»*.

Comment: @Eagle Спасибо.

Comment: Я поставил лишнюю запятую «…файлов, путём…». Сравните: *Дерево ежегодно утолщается путем нарастания новых слоев древесины.* А. В. Кожевников, По тундрам, лесам, степям и пустыням.

Comment: @Eagle Оцените мой текущий вариант, если не затруднит :) "Файлы, имена которых включают такие суффиксы, должны создаваться в виде копий (для чего тебе потребуется продвинутый файловый менеджер или какой-то скрипт, а также — назначить соответствующие сочетания клавиш), и такие копии следует использовать только в качестве временных; например, в качестве простой системы контроля версий."

Comment: «для чего тебе потребуется продвинутый файловый менеджер или какой-то скрипт, а также — назначить соответствующие сочетания клавиш» — непонятна мысль. «Потребуется менеджер, а также — назначить» — потребуется назначить?

Comment: Может так: «для чего тебе потребуется продвинутый файловый менеджер или какой-то скрипт, в которых можно назначить для этого соответствующие сочетания клавиш».

Comment: Исправьте опечатки в заголовке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У «него/неё» и «этого» немного разный смысл.

«Него/неё» — это личные местоимения.

> **Ли́чные местоиме́ния** — местоимения, которые указывают на предмет, но
> не называют его.
> В группу личных местоимений входят такие слова как:
> я, мы, ты, вы, он, она, оно, они. [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

*«Наружный тюнинг автомобиля и используемые для него товары»* тут «него» заменят «Наружный тюнинг автомобиля», чтоб не повторять второй раз одно и тоже: *«Наружный тюнинг автомобиля и используемые для наружного тюнинга автомобиля товары».*

«Этого» — это указательное местоимение в данном случае.

> **Указа́тельные местоиме́ния или демонстрати́вы (лат. pronomina
> demonstrativa)** — местоимения, указывающие на то, какой объект имеет в
> виду говорящий, а также на расположение объекта относительно
> говорящего (либо адресата).
>   ...
>  Указательными местоимениями в
> русском языке являются слова: этот, тот, такой, таков, столько, а
> также устаревшее сей. [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

> **Это** — 3. *указательное*. **Употребляется для указания на предмет, лицо и
> т. п., названные в предшествующем повествовании.** Батюшка у окна читал
> Придворный календарь, ежегодно им получаемый. Эта книга имела всегда
> сильное на него влияние. Пушкин, Капитанская дочка. В средней полосе
> Сибири первые заморозки начинаются уже в конце августа. --- С этого
> времени начинают опадать цветы, сохнут травы и раскрашиваются во все
> цвета радуги --- осинники. Марков, Строговы. | **в знач. сущ. э́тот,
> э́того, м.; э́та, э́той, ж.; э́то, э́того, ср. *Силен в плечах Кастрюк
> и смел в битвах. Этот может вести за собой на врага. С. Бородин,
> Дмитрий Донской.*** || в знач. сущ. э́тот, э́того, м.; э́та, э́той,
> ж.; э́то, э́того, ср. Последний из названных. Первая бросилась
> обнимать Марью Александровну Наталья Дмитриевна; за ней Анна
> Николаевна, за этой Фелисата Михайловна. Достоевский, Дядюшкин сон.
> Снова и снова говорили рабочие делегаты с фабричными инспекторами, эти
> уверяли, что сделают все — и не делали ничего. Фурманов, Талка.
> [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевной]

*«Наружный тюнинг автомобиля и используемые для этого товары»* — «этого» указывает на предмет «Наружный тюнинг автомобиля», о котором говорилось ранее.

В данном случае можно говорить и так, и так.

---

Не имеет значения, мы говорим о процессах или нет. «Тюнинг» — это просто существительное со значением действия, как, например, «бег». Для таких существительных в данном случае нет особых правил; правила те же, что и для других существительных.